# no puedo editar datos de mi base de datos en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es CRUD con laravel, y hasta ahora puedo almacenar nuevos datos sin problemas en la base de datos, pero no puedo editarlos.
Esta es mi vista para editar:

```
<form action="{{ route('product.update',$products->id) }}" method="put" >
    <label for="nombre">nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value = "{{$products -> nombre}}">

    <label for="precio">precio</label>
    <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" value = "{{$products -> precio}}">

    <select name="id_marca" id="marcas">
    @foreach($marcas as $marca)
        @if($marca -> id == $products -> id_marca)
            <option value="{{$marca->id}}" selected>{{$marca->name}}</option>
        @else
            <option value="{{$marca->id}}">{{$marca->name}}</option>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="editar">
</form>
```

Lo que hago con esta vista es capturar el nombre, precio y marca de un producto. 
En mi archivo de rutas esta esto:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    route::resource('product','Producto\ProductoController');
});
```

Y el archivo ProductoController es este:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Producto;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ProductoController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $products = \App\Models\Producto\Producto :: select('producto.id as id','producto.nombre as producto','precio','marca.name as marca') -> join('marca','marca.id','=','producto.id_marca') -> get();
        return View('product/product') -> with('products',$products);
    }

    public function create(){
        $marcas = \App\Models\Producto\Marca :: all();
        return view('product.create') -> with('marcas',$marcas);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $datos = request()->all();
        \App\Models\Producto\Producto :: create($request->all());
        return redirect() -> route('product.index');
    }

    public function edit($id){
        $marcas = \App\Models\Producto\Marca :: all();
        $products = \App\Models\Producto\Producto :: FindOrFail($id);
        return view('product.edit', array('products'=>$products, 'marcas'=>$marcas));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id){
        $input = $request->all();
        \App\Models\Producto\Producto :: where('id','=', $id)->update($input);
        return redirect()->route('/product');
    }

    public function show($id){}

    public function destroy($id){}
}
```

Lo que creo que esta pasando es que por algun motivo no se esta ejecutando la funcion update del controlador pero no se porque. Alguien pordria decrime que esta mal por favor (estoy usando Laravel 5.2)

Comment: ¿Qué aparece cuando se envía el formulario?

Comment: nada, la vista se queda en blanco. En la URL me sale esto: "http://localhost/appmarket/public/product/6?nombre=papa&precio=3&id_marca=2". Estoy intentando editar un producto que ya tengo en la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

Veo que En esta línea usas el método `PUT` a nivel de la etiqueta de apertura del formulario, pero HTML como tal solo tiene:

```
<form action="{{ route('product.update',$products->id) }}" method="put" >
```

- GET
- POST

Por lo tanto para identificar el verbo a usar deberás incluir el helper `@method` de Blade justo después

```
<form action="{{ route('product.update',$products->id) }}" method="POST">
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
```

Además también te haría falta el uso del helper `@csrf` con lo cual el código completo debería ser:

```
<form action="{{ route('product.update',$products->id) }}" method="POST">
{{ method_field('PUT') }} 
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: te comento que la solucion si eran los helpers, solo que creo que es distinto en la version 5.2. En vez de usar @method('PUT') y @csrf, utilice {{ method_field('PUT') }} y {{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: Cierto @JavierMartinezBarriga me basé en la versión que uso sin embargo que bueno lo solucionaste

Answer (score 0):

La solucion era utilizar helpers en la vista de editar:

```
<form action="{{ route('product.update',$products->id) }}" method="POST" >
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <label for="nombre">nombre</label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value = "{{$products -> nombre}}">

        <label for="precio">precio</label>
        <input type="text" name="precio" id="precio" value = "{{$products -> precio}}">

        <select name="id_marca" id="marcas">
        @foreach($marcas as $marca)
            @if($marca -> id == $products -> id_marca)
                <option value="{{$marca->id}}" selected>{{$marca->name}}</option>
            @else
                <option value="{{$marca->id}}">{{$marca->name}}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="editar">
    </form>
```

Comment: Hola recuerda marcar alguna de las 2 respuestas como aceptada, de esa forma se entiende que la pregunta ya esta solucionada